# Error in unit testing on pre-processing raw data

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

```
import pandas as pd
import spacy
from spacy.lang.en.stop_words import STOP_WORDS
import nltk

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")

class fileread:
    def readfile(self):
        file_path = 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\Emails\\DEP72303-SYSOUT.txt'

        with open(file_path, 'r') as text:
            return text.read()
class preprocess:
    fi=fileread()
    def remove(self):
        return re.sub('^[\sA-Za-z0-9]', '',self.fi.readfile())

    def preprocess(self):
        doc = nlp(self.remove())
        filtered = []
        for token in doc:
            if token.is_stop or token.is_punct:
                continue

            filtered.append(token.lemma_)

        return " ".join(filtered)
pre=preprocess()
output=pre.preprocess()
tokens=output.split("\n")
print(tokens)
```

This code is take a reads a file which has raw data and pre-processing is done using regex expression, removing stop words and punctuation and in the last lemmatization is done.

## Unit testing on the above program is:

```
import unittest
import os  # Make sure this line is present
from preprocessing import preprocess

class MockFileRead:
    # Mocking the file read class to use the temporary file
    def readfile(self):
        with open('test_input.txt', 'r') as text:
            return text.read()

class TestPreprocess(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_preprocess(self):
        # Assuming you have a sample input file with known content for testing
        sample_input = "Sample text content for testing purposes."

        # Create a temporary file for testing
        with open('test_input.txt', 'w') as temp_file:
            temp_file.write(sample_input)

        preprocess_instance = preprocess()
        preprocess_instance.fi = MockFileRead()

        # Expected output after preprocessing
        expected_output = "sample text content test purpose"

        self.assertEqual(preprocess_instance.preprocess(), expected_output)

        # Clean up: Remove the temporary file
        os.remove('test_input.txt')

if __name__ == 'main':
    unittest.main()
```

In the above program my expected output is: sample text content test purpose
but the output I got is: ample text content testing purpose

How do I resolve the code and get the correct output?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question might get flagged as too broad and missing a specific problem. As it is now, it might be too close to a "code dump" - "debug my code" type of question. You can probably improve it after reading [ask] and [mre]. Consider taking the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

It's currently trying to remove only single characters or digits at the beginning of each line. To remove all non-alphanumeric characters, you should use a pattern like [^a-zA-Z0-9\s]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).